# International Education Spending

Tags: education, global

I am interested in looking at the relationship between money spent on education (by country) versus educational ranking (by country). I am looking for a database that shows something like amount of money that is spent on students in different countries as well as the education ranking of those countries.  The data can come from more than one source (say one for money spent and one for education ranking) as I can merge them myself once I have the data sources.

Answer (score 1):

The question on "spending money on eductaion"  might have an answer here:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49589/is-education-in-europe-really-this-cheap

There are links for Europe and other countries.

I think the ranking you better do yourself. There are numerous ways to quantify the efficiency, or quality, of education.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some databases on Quandl that show government expenditures on education when I searched for "expenditure education" within each database:

World Bank Africa Development Indicators: https://www.quandl.com/data/WADI?keyword=education

Federal Reserve Economic Data: https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED?keyword=expenditure%20education

United Nations Global Indicators: https://www.quandl.com/data/UGID?keyword=expenditure%20education

Asian Development Bank: https://www.quandl.com/data/ADB?keyword=expenditure%20education

National Bureau of Statistics China: https://www.quandl.com/data/NBSC?keyword=expenditure%20education

World Bank Education Statistics: https://www.quandl.com/data/WEDU?keyword=expenditure%20education

Hope this helps... Disclosure: I work for Quandl.